# Metric compatibility from existence of normal coordinate

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, geodesics

It is well known that for a Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$, one can define a torsionless and metric-compatible connection $\nabla$, and then use $\nabla$ to construct geodesics and [normal coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates). In these normal coordinates, $g = \delta$ (or in Lorentzian signature, $g = \eta$).

I wonder if one can turn the logic around. Suppose I am given a torsionless connection $\nabla$, and I use it to define geodesics and normal coordinates. Then I grab a metric $g$ and declare that at any point, $g = \delta$ in the normal coordinates (of course I should only focus on those coordinates with orthonormal basis vector w.r.t. $g$). Am I guaranteed that $\nabla g = 0$?

Naively, I would think that: in the normal coordinate at point $p$, $\Gamma|_p = 0$. Then $\nabla g = \partial g$ at $p$. So I should study $\partial g|_p$ in the normal coordinate, which I think naively is zero (from the intuition that in the usual discussion on normal coordinates, $g = \delta + O(x^2)$).

Comment: I do not understand well the question. You have a $\nabla$-geodesic coordinate system **centered** at some point $p$ and defined in an open  neighborhood $U\ni p$. So $\Gamma|_p = 0$. Are you assuming that $g|_p=\delta$ simply or, more strongly as I think,  $g|_q = \delta$ for every $q\in U$? Similarly, are you interested in $\nabla_q g=0$ everywhere in $U$, right?

Comment: However, if I have understood well your question, $\nabla_q g \neq 0$ in general except for $q=p$. This is because $\partial g=0$ in $U$, but  $\nabla_q g = \partial_q g$ only for $q=p$, in general, from the standard action of affine connections on $(0,2)$ tensors and from the fact that in geodesic coordinates of a torsionless connection, the $\Gamma$s vanish at the center of the coordinates only.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Yes indeed, fix any $p$ and find a normal coordinate around $p$ means  that only at $p$, $\Gamma_p = 0$. So in my question, I want to assume the following: for any $p$ and then pick any $\nabla$-geodesic coordinate centered at $p$, I want $g_p = \delta$ (just at the center $p$). Note that I also want this to hold when we exhaust all $p$  (and the normal coordinates as well). When $g$ is compatible with $\nabla$, I think this is just the standard result: $g_p = δ$ for any $p$ and any associated normal coordinates around $p$. But what happens when $g$ is NOT compatible?

Comment: @ValterMoretti Maybe there is some issue in normalization of the basis vector which I am not careful about, when I say "$g_p = \delta$".

Comment: OK, I think I have understood...

Comment: So, you have a smooth assignment of bases on $T_pM$ varying $p\in M$ and you use this assignment to define an atlas of geodesic coordinates (for a given torsionfree affine connection $\nabla$) centered at every $p\in M$. Next you declare that all these bases are orthonormal with respect to a metric $g$. The question is whether or not $\nabla$   is $g$-metric. I think the answer is generally no. Suppose it is the case. Per direct inspection, I think it is easy to change the initial assignment of bases to produce a new metric which does not fulfill the condition.

Comment: @ValterMoretti After given more more thoughts I think the answer to the current question is indeed no, as you said. I'll think a bit more, perhaps the setting could be "improved" to yield a positive answer (the question arises from asking why we introduce the metric compatibility in the first place in general relativity, and hoping that it can be derived by combining the equivalence principle and some other reasonable assumptions). Thanks.

Comment: @Lelouch it cannot be derived from those assumptions.